Wix4 syntax/conditional changes
I am seeing changes between Wix 3.14 and Wix 4 in my generated MSI file ...
I have certain properties that

I want to inherit from previous installation/registry
Allow person to pass properties on the command line that would override the previous settings
Default to some other value if neither condition 1 or 2 is met

Say I have a config.wxi and I define a variable like this:
<?define Absent = "#-9998" ?>
Then in product.wxs I have:
<Property Id="MFATIMEOUT" Value="$(var.Absent)">
   <RegistrySearch Id="MFATimeOutSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.BaseRegistryKey)" Name="MFATimeOut" Type="raw" />
</Property>

Under Wix 3.14 this worked to set the value if it had not been set:
<SetProperty Id="MFATIMEOUT" Value="0" After="AppSearch" Condition='MFATIMEOUT="$(var.Absent)"' Sequence='first'/>

However, under Wix4, it is not working ... what I see in an Edit field is -9998. (At some point for numerics, I tweak them and remove the # sign before display in an installer dialog). It indicates to me that SetProperty did not get called because the conditional was not met. I did modify the conditional to set it to '1 or (MFATIMEOUT="$(var.Absent)")' and it did set the value to 0 because it evaluated to true.
However, under Wix4, I can modify my source and it will work to give the correct value if I code a raw conditional...
<SetProperty Id="MFATIMEOUT" Value="0" After="AppSearch" Condition='MFATIMEOUT=-9998' Sequence='first'/>

So, I have to change the conditional that worked in Wix 3: 'MFATIMEOUT="$(var.Absent)"', to a new conditional that works in Wix4: MFATIMEOUT=-9998
I am curious to what changed where what I had no longer works... Is it how I was coding $(var.Absent) ? Exactly what?
FOLLOWUP:
Also, I noticed that for that case, If I changed the definition of $var.Absent to -9998 instead of #-9998, then it works. I cannot tell you why originally it was #-9998, but only that it was that way because it worked... so much obscure Wix stuff...

I don't see anything in the snippets you've provided that should behave differently in WiX v3 to WiX v4.
Is it possible the type of the registry key you are searching for changed? If it is no longer numeric the Windows Installer won't put a # in front of it any longer.

Well, I have to handle when the registry key isn't even there when it is a a new installation. I was testing this case because that is where it manifests itself. Somehow, v4 is handling the conditional differently.

You'll need to compare verbose installation log files. I do not see anything in what you've provided thus far that should create a difference in the MSIs. The log files will tell what is going on.
